# R code pivot column to rows and rows to columns

Tags: r, pivot, tidyverse

I'm new to RStudio and I've been struggling on this issue for 2 days and came to the conclusion that I need help.

I have a data frame looking like this :

```
ISO  Indicator 2009  2010 2011 
ARB  Use of electricity 0.5 0.5 0.4
CSS  Population  2.5 3.5 0.5
```

What I want to do get is

```
ISO Year Use of Electricity Population
ARB 2009 0.5 na
ARB 2010 0.5 na
ARB 2011 0.4 na
CSS 2009 na 2.5
CSS 2010 na 3.5
CSS 2011 na 0.5
```

I started of with a "gather" function to create the Year column and then I transformed Year to numeric and created a result column for the values. I then tried "spread" I get an error on the type of my data frame. 
Is there a way to make this pivoting in one step, if so I'd be happy to hear it.
I thought about adding a row up top and name it Year to use a pivot function but I'm not sure how to proceed. 
Is the problem coming from the fact that my data frame should be converted into a matrix?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You can try the function transpose, by doing t(dataframe)

Comment: I considered the transpose because I had seen another similar thread but I think the column ISO was problematic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your data is

```r
df <- read_table2("ISO  Indicator 2009  2010 2011
ARB  Use_of_electricity 0.5 0.5 0.4
CSS  Population  2.5 3.5 0.5")
```

Using `dplyr`/`tidyr`:

```r
df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols=as.character(2009:2011), names_to="Year") %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from="Indicator")
```

yields

```r
# A tibble: 6 x 4
  ISO   year  Use_of_electricity Population
  <chr> <chr>              <dbl>      <dbl>
1 ARB   2009                 0.5       NA  
2 ARB   2010                 0.5       NA  
3 ARB   2011                 0.4       NA  
4 CSS   2009                NA          2.5
5 CSS   2010                NA          3.5
6 CSS   2011                NA          0.5
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Martin Gal it worked like a charm. You saved me from further headaches!